# smps and ground layer (4 layer PCB)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, grounding, ground-plane

I am designing a 4 layer smps (low noise) and I have a some design philosophy questions .

1. Under the transformer (that separates primary from secondary) should I extend the ground planes ( one primary side and second secondary side) all the way to mid transformer ( I keep a few mm of creepage between the 2 grounds) or should I extend the ground only to the pins of transformer (both sides) ?
2. Output (secondary side) I have a  common mode choke on DC output. Should I make a ground plane for the CMC and wires output (small ground plane in addition to secondary ground) or I should keep the main ground as big as possible and output of CMC + wires with only traces ?
3. Bridge rectifier has a capacitor on output and after capacitor, 2 ferrite beads on positive and negative. Should I create a ground layer (small) for bridge rectifier + C and then declare the main primary ground (much bigger) after those ferrite beads ?
4. On AC side, I have a CMC , Y capacitors etc. Should I use a ground layer on the AC or traces (hot and neutral) without ground layer .

   Sorry for so many questions but I have read a lot of articles and I am still unclear on whats the best way to design ground planes for ultra low noise smps.

Comment: "I keep a few mm of creepage between the 2 grounds" What does the norms in the countries you intend to sell it in say about your clearance and creepage _requirements_?

Comment: We are on the norm taken in consideration the pollution factor as well

Comment: I have a circuit that I want PCB recommendations on but I won't show the schematic nor the transformer construction nor the EMC expectations - how much help can I expect?

Comment: Andy this is not about circuit or schematic . Its philosophy (if I can say that) of the ground plane.

Comment: if you would not like to share layout, a diagram showing these problems would help experts more to answer better. Pictures say more than Words !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformer will induce eddy currents into any metal around it; planes will be proportionally more vulnerable; I'd have a square of copper under the Xformer to intercept the Hfields, and tie that square at ONE place to the surrounding "GND planes."

How *low* is "ultra low noise opamps"?

Here is what Signal Chain Explorer predicts (we have NOT included a transformer flux-leakage candidate in the Hfield (HFI) interference table).

[image]

Input from sensor is 1 millivolt; each opamp is 3,000MHz UGBW so the various interferers get amplified and passed along; GainStage 1 and 2 use 100 ohm and 11 ohm resistors, to get 20dB gain in each. High values of resistors cause massive phaseshift, and the opamp gain stages become oscillators out at 500MHz.

The "Gargoyles" are enabled (top right button), but only HFI interferers are active; I disabled EFI, PSI, GPI. All but PSI require the "interconnect" button active; the default interconnect between stages is 14mm long PCB trace, 1mm wide and 1.5mm above the GND plane. The Magnetic field loop is 14mm high and 1.5mm above plane. The various Hfield aggressors are modeled as infinitely long straight wires. The 2 HFI aggressors are switchreg at 2MHz and ARM clock line at 100MHz.

Note the SNR, with Gargoyles active, is -48dB. With Gargoyles off, SNR is +29 dB defined by the 12 millivolt RMS output thermal noise.

Here are details of the HFI table of available (its editable) aggressors, plus output trash magnitudes and which stages produce the trash.

[image]

==========================================

What to do, to improve the circuit?
---Do not place a MCU clock trace 1mm away from 300MHz bandwidth Signal Chain.
   {this is the dominant aggressor: 90 volts RMS output}

---Do not place a switchregulator 10mm away from 300MHz BW signal Chain.

---The random noise peaks near 300MHz (opamps are 3,000MHz UGBW; Av = 10X);
   Reduce the bandwidth to 3MHz (add a final R+C passive low-pass-filter: 1Kohm 
   and 47pF) and the noise power is reduced by 100:1 and the noise voltage is
   reduced by sqrt(100) or 10:1, and you have 20dB better SNR and 3+ bits more
   ENOB.

---What happened when ALL FOUR of the Gargoyles (interferers) are enabled?
The 2nd strongest is electric-fields [also MCU clock at 1mm distance] causing 0.944 volts RMS trash floor. The 3rd is Ground Plane currents [from 0.1 amps of SwitchReg return-currents sharing 5 squares (0.002 ohms) GND plane resistance]. The 4rth is PSI --- power supply trash and finite OpAmp PSRR [ the active Power Supply trash sources are: 60Hz, 120Hz, and 100MHz ringing of SwitchReg, each at 10mV level].

Does SNR degrade when all four Gargoyles are enabled? No. Unless we move the MCU clock far away from our Signal Chain. And move the SwitchReg away.

With no MCU and no SwitchReg interference, what remains? the 120Hz power supply ripple into gain stage#1, which produces 110 uV RMS on Signal Chain output.

======================================

How to design the GND plane, once MCU clock and SwitchRegs are TAKEN FAR AWAY?
Use slits to guide aggressor currents away from the Signal Chain. This requires you to understand what aggressors remain, how those currents need to flow, and sketch out a finite-element-model of the GND plane and how the bad currents need to flow; add slits to isolate your gain-of-1,000X circuit from GND voltates: V = Ignd * Rgnd, at 500 microOhms per square of copper foil.